# Why i am getting a weird time series graph in python?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-science, data-analysis

I'm doing a time series exercice. I have the following data :

| date(indexed) | Year | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-04-30 | 2000 | 274633 |
| 2000-05-31 | 2000 | 256064 |
| ...... | ...... | ...... |
| 2023-01-31 | 2023 | 535791 |
| 2023-02-28 | 2023 | 375202 |

I'm trying to print the evolution of the Salary but i am getting a weird messed up graph
[image]

The code that i am using is the following.

```
def seasonal_decomposition(data, column, periode, title, name):
    decomposition = seasonal_decompose(data[column], period=periode)
    seasonal = decomposition.seasonal
    trend = decomposition.trend
    resid = decomposition.resid

    plt.figure(1 , figsize =(12,8))
    plt.plot(data.index, data[column], 'k')
    plt.legend([column])
    plt.xlabel("Years")
    plt.ylabel(column)
    plt.title(title)

    plt.figure(2 , figsize =(20,13))
    plt.suptitle(" Trend, Seasonality and Residuals of the " + column + " time series")

    plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
    plt.plot(data.index,trend)
    plt.xlabel("Years")
    plt.ylabel(column + name)
    plt.title("The Trend of" + name )

    plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
    plt.plot(data.index,seasonal)
    plt.xlabel("Years")
    plt.ylabel(column + name)
    plt.title("Seasonality" + name )

    plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
    plt.plot(data.index,resid) 
    plt.xlabel("Years")
    plt.ylabel(column + name)
    plt.title("Residuals" + name )

    plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
    plt.plot(data.index,trend)
    plt.plot(data.index,seasonal)
    plt.plot(data.index,resid)
    plt.title("All of the components")
    plt.legend(['Trend', 'Seasonal', 'Residuals'],loc='lower left')
    plt.show()
```

I don't know why i am getting a graph like that. And it's the same for all graphs in the function.

Do you have any idea ?
Thanks.

I don't understand why i am getting such a graph

Comment: Is your dataframe sorted on the index?

Comment: thank you for you answer, i have just checked. it works